# How to reuse SurfaceHolder on WallpaperService ,

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, live-wallpaper, surfaceholder

How to reuse `SurfaceHolder` on `WallpaperService`,

I want to Loop switch the content to Surface on the WallpaperService.
1."play movie", 2."draw a picture" , 3."play movie" .looping

It work.
1. playPlayer()   2. playImage().

An error occurs.
1. playPlayer()   2. playImage() 3. playPlayer( ) error

Mediaplayer cannot connect to Surface again.

```
2018-12-10 16:10:15.535 584-938/? E/BufferQueueProducer: [com.myapp.LiveWallpaperService#1] connect: already    connected (cur=2 req=3)
2018-12-10 16:10:15.535 2272-2913/? E/SurfaceUtils: Failed to connect to surface 0xa6b7a808, err -22
2018-12-10 16:10:15.535 2272-2913/? E/MediaPlayerService: setVideoSurfaceTexture failed: -22
2018-12-10 16:10:15.535 2272-2913/? D/NuPlayerDriver: reset(0xa7118230) at state 2
```

**Code**

```
@Override
public void onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {         
        Switch and call 
        playPlayer() ,playImage() , playPlayer( )....
    }
    super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated( SurfaceHolder holder ) {
    super.onSurfaceCreated(holder);
    surfaceHolder   = holder;
}

private void playImage(){
    Canvas canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile( "jpeg" );
    try {
        canvas.drawBitmap( bitmap, 0, 0, paint );
        bitmap.recycle();
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost( canvas );
    }
}

private void playPlayer()
    try {
        mediaPlayer     = new MediaPlayer();
        surface         = surfaceHolder.getSurface();
        mediaPlayer.setSurface( surface );
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion( MediaPlayer mp ) {
                mp.setSurface( null );
                mp.setDisplay( null );
                surface     = null;
                if( mp.isPlaying() ) {
                    mp.stop();
                }
                mp.reset();
                mp.release();
                mp = null;
            }
        });
        mediaPlayer.setLooping( false );
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener( new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared( MediaPlayer mp ) {
                mp.start();
            }
        });
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource( "***.mp4" );
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thankyou.